# How to add Docker Support for Asp.Net Core 2.0 targeting full .Net Framework 4.7

Tags: .net, docker, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

I  have an ASP.Net Core 2.0 application targeting .Net Framework 4.7 (full).
I want to use Docker for it but VS 2017 15.5 does not allow me to Add Docker Support to it. (this is not supported jet).
My question is: Is there any work-around this issue.
If not, Can I still use docker with this project somehow and debug it in VS 2017?
Please help
Thanks

**Update**
I need to use .NET Full version because I am using 3rd party libraries that do not jet support .net core like NHibernate, and I don't want to use EF Core.
Also I am building on microservices architecture and want each mecroservice to be deployed in its own container.

Comment: Also I don't know what docker image I must use for this...
Should I use microsoft/aspnet:4.7.1-windowsservercore-ltsc2016 or microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0-nanoserver-sac2016?
Or is there an image with both .Net Core 2.0 and .Net Framework 4.7 installed?

Comment: Nano only supports .NET Core, not the full framework. That's why the image size is only a "few" MBs.  Server Core does support both but its size is in the GB range. *Why* do you want to use the full framework on Docker? You *can* add the required dockerfile yourself but your container would be so large that deployment would take too long

Comment: [This article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/11/09/creating-a-minimal-asp-net-core-windows-container/) describes the difference between the targets. Note that using the latest Nano image requieres only 256MB

Comment: If you do want to use the full framework you can use the same dockerfile and replace `microsoft/aspnetcore` with `microsoft/aspnet`. [That image](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnet/) is based on Server Core (thus a lot larger) and contains .NET 4.7.1

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I need to use Full.Net Framework because i use 3rd party libraries that does not jet support .net core (like NHibernate) and No, I don't want to use EF Core. Also I am building on microservice architecture and deploy each microservice in it's own docker container

Comment: then you have conflcting requirements. You should use the `microsoft/aspnet` image but that won't be "micro". As for "microservice architecture" that's a marketing name. It's services which means they should be independent, not share state, independently deployable and all that stuff. Using a large (GB-sized) container image means you'll probably have to bundle some services in the same image to reduce the cost of deployment.

Comment: Besides, NH is stagnating and rather heavyweight. Jet isn't needed unless you need to use Access (you can use eg EPPlus to read/write Excel files). Do you **really** need to use .NET Framework for all services? In a proper *micro* architecture you should be able to develop each service individually, which means you can *isolate* those that need legacy support. You should be able to build 20 independent aspnetcore containers and 1-2 large aspnet container. If you can't, you don't have a micro architecture

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos NH is not the only one, there is MassTransit too and maybe some other that does not jet support .Net Core, and my deployment server will be local (on premise) not in cloud, so deployment size is not an issue. But I accept your suggestion, not every service will be full .net, and I will look that the one that need be full .net will be deployed inside one container.

Comment: Then why are you usind *Docker*? What do you expect to gain? In fact, you don't need Docker that much when deploying to cloud. It's for *local* deployments that you need it, to isolate services and allow individual deployments. And size *does* matter for local server too because it determines how fast/often you can deploy. Although in this case the base image will be deployed only once.

Comment: Because I want to unify my development/deployment environment across multiple teams, and on top of that (like you wrote) to isolate services and allow individual deployment. What do you suggest then? To use classic development and to deploy to an IIS server, then to deploy all dependent service (like sql, RabitMq, RavenDB...) to their own servers The problem I'm having with this is that then I need to maintain all that servers across multiple teams and locations. The way I want it is to create a virtual machine that have all the stuff a developer will need to develop and test it's code.

Comment: And then ship that virtual machine to all developers (teams) in the remote locations. And be sure that each one will have the same development/testing environment already set up in the virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this [Dockerfile](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Capgemini/dockerfiles/master/net-build/Dockerfile)

it has *both `.Net Core 2.0` and `.Net Framework 4.7`*

and this is the full description on the [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/capgemini/net-build/)

Comment: Ok, that will do. Now I only need help creating Dockerfile and Docker-compose that will work from VS2017. Although It don't have to work from VS 2017 it can be run from the CLI, but then I need somehow to debug it.

Comment: how about this.. https://www.scrum-tips.com/2017/12/27/understanding-docker-with-visual-studio-2017-part-2/ 
let me know if its not what you're lookin for. .

Comment: you should be able to combine it with previous `Dockerfile`

Comment: I tried adding all necessary files,but when I build the solution in VS 2017 I get this error: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: stream docker-compose
And the error happens in : 
Task "CreateComposeVsGeneratedFiles" in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets File

Comment: could you give more information about your docker-compose,?you are using VS 2017 (15.5) right..?

Comment: Sure, my VS 2017 is version 15.5.2 and I have no more updates to install.
Because of VS 2017 as is now, is not supporting docker for ASP.NET Core 2.0 targeting Full .NET Framework, I have manually added the needed files. VS did recognize them all, and the solution is set to build the docker-compose. My Docker compose file is simple: 
    <code>`services:
      webapplication7:
        image: webapplication7
        build:
          context: .\WebApplication7
          dockerfile: Dockerfile`    </code>
It is located in the solution root (where the .sln file is).

Comment: The compose.override file contains port, environment variable and default network node that VS adds to it. (I did copy it from another solution that works and have adapted it to match my file/folder/service locations and names)).

Comment: Hi Luka, did you figure out what was happening? I think I'm hitting the same rock.